# Datagrid is not properly refreshing on row delete

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I am working with a datagrid in WPF which is bound to a collectionviewsource. The viewsource is bound to an observable collection named *Rows*.

The datagrid has add and delete functions which function properly except on small problem.

Here are images:

[image]

The datagrid has more data than this. Each test starts off with two sequences (the two rows you see belong to a single test) and they are grouped and sorted by a unique ID.

[image]

I have clicked the red "X" to delete the row. I will now click the "Add" button located at the top-left of the image.

[image]

The data is still there.

These are my add and delete functions:

```
private void Add(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var testRun = e.Parameter as TestRun;
            if (testRun != null)
            {
                var numberOfRows = testRun.Property.GetValue("numberOfRows").ToNullable<int>().GetValueOrDefault(2);
                numberOfRows++;
                testRun.Property.SetValue("numberOfRows", numberOfRows.ToString());
                this.Rows.Add(new ESCHandle(testRun, numberOfRows));
            }
        }

private void Delete(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var esc = e.Parameter as ESCHandle;
        if (esc != null)
        {
            this.Rows.Remove(esc);
            var numberOfRows = esc.TestRun.Property.GetValue("numberOfRows").ToNullable<int>().GetValueOrDefault(2);
            numberOfRows--;
            esc.TestRun.Property.SetValue("numberOfRows", numberOfRows.ToString());

        }
    }
```

The ESC object is properly removed from the observablecollection on Delete. But on when I add another ESC object/row to the colleciton and datagrid, the data is somehow copied to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You may forget to call a refresh method on datagrid to update its visual elements, such as the rows.

`Datagrid.Items.Refresh()`, as described here:

http://programmer.wrighton.org/2009/01/wpf-datagrid-items-refresh.html

This problem may be caused because PropertyChange is not raised properly.